# User controls are not available in the toolbox in VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have created the WPF user control and WPF window  in class library project. Controls are public.

These controls are available for other project of the same solution. I can see them in the toolbox of the VS2010 when i add project reference from the WPF application project.

However, when i create some WPF application project outside the solution and add reference to the my user control library project, the controls do not appear in the toolbox! (My applications XAML file is open when I try to see them in toolbox to drag-drop on the application's main XAML)

What makes the controls avilable to the outside world when their assembly is referenced by the consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking on the toolbox and selecting `Choose Items` From that form click browse and select your DLL. That should put the controls in the toolbox for you.

Comment: `Tools->Options->Windows Form Designer -> General -> AutoToolBoxPopulate` property is set to TRUE in VS 2010. But strangely, toolbox did not update when i referenced the assemblies containing WPF controls. (even after building the solution !)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your new WPF project you need to set an XML namespace where you reference your user control library. Then you can use your controls in the XAML.

For example :

thats an xml namespace definition in the XAML:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
               assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And how you can use a control from this control library

```
< toolkit:ListPicker />
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Right click inside the toolbox and select "Show All".